# Python Tkinter Confusion

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python and programming in general also new to stack overflow. Any help would be appreciated, I am just messing around with code for fun to get a feel for it.

My goal is to change the box from red to blue when the button is pushed.
I set the var rec1c to 'red' then set it to 'blue' when the button is pushed. I ran the code and the box never turned blue. I put the print statements in to see if it changed, the box never turned blue. I am confused as to why because I kept pressing the button and the first print statement never turned back to red. the second time pressing both statements are blue i thought it would change back after thinking about689 it that's why i put those there

my questions are

Is it possible to accomplish my goal? 
If so how? 
Is there a better way to doing it than my way? 
also i tried putting all my code into the question but it cut a lot of it out so I deleted all but the necessary code. Assume the syntax is correct.

```
class PythonTest(Frame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):
    self.parent.title("Python!")
    self.style = Style()
    self.style.theme_use("default")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    self.canw = 300
    self.canh = 400

    paper = Canvas(self, width=self.canw, height=self.canh)
    paper.pack()

    self.rec1c = 'red'
    self.rec1o = 'red'
    self.rec1 = paper.create_rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300, fill=self.rec1c, outline=self.rec1o)

    self.translate = Button(self, text="Change Color!", command=self.toB)
    self.translate.place(x=50, y=50)

def toB(self):
    print(self.rec1c)
    self.rec1c = 'blue'
    print(self.rec1c)
    Tk.update
```

Comment: can you put the entire class?

Comment: just did sorry it didn't work the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `paper` from `toB()` use `self.paper` and to change color add `self.paper.itemconfig(self.rec1, fill=self.rec1c)` in `toB` method.

```
class PythonTest(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Python!")
        #self.style = Style()
        #self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canw = 300
        self.canh = 400

        self.paper = Canvas(self, width=self.canw, height=self.canh)
        self.paper.pack()

        self.rec1c = 'red'
        self.rec1o = 'red'
        self.rec1 = self.paper.create_rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300, fill=self.rec1c, outline=self.rec1o)

        self.translate = Button(self, text="Translate to Pig Latin", command=self.toB)
        self.translate.place(x=50, y=50)

    def toB(self):
        print(self.rec1c)
        self.rec1c = 'blue'
        print(self.rec1c)
        self.paper.itemconfig(self.rec1, fill=self.rec1c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of `self.rec1c` will not propagate any changes to canvas elements whose attributes were defined using `self.rec1c`. `self.rec1c` has a new value, but the canvas elements still happily point to the old value, and will continue to do so no matter what happens to `self.rec1c`.

If you want the rectangle's attributes to change, you need to change them explicitly with `itemconfig`.

```
self.paper = Canvas(self, width=self.canw, height=self.canh)
self.paper.pack()

self.rec1 = paper.create_rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300, fill="red", outline="red")

#later, in toB...

self.paper.itemconfig(self.rec1, fill="blue")
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I met my goal.

Comment: @killer Glad to hear it :-) Feel free to accept whichever answer you found most useful.